# Maven process test resources

Tags: testing, maven, dependencies

I have a maven project that has a test-scope dependency on an artifact. 
But due to some reason the artifact is not available on the new environment that I am running this project on. So the process-test-resources step fails since maven cannot find the artifact to copy.

Does anyone know a way to prevent maven build from failing when a test artifact is not found? Or maybe modify the step to exclude this artifact? I am using -DskipTests=true flag so it seems to me this test-scope dependency artifact shouldn't matter.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the pom to not have that test scope dependency anymore and remove anything that needs it or just find the artifact ..

Comment: Thanks but I cannot change the project and the requirement is that I cannot find the artifact and place it in repository.

Comment: hahah... those are some silly requirements. You will need to find the artifact.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing your option to `-Dmaven.test.skip=true`, but the documentation doesn't mention skipping test resource management explicitly: see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html

Comment: Thank you but I tried both -Dmaven.test.skip=true or -DskipTests=true. neither worked for me.

Comment: @BiGzZ I have to say that I ended up moving all but the more trivial tests to separate projects, that depend on the projects they hold tests for.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an artifact file available, you may try to install it manually into your local repository.

This is straight from the [maven-install-plugin doc](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html)

```
mvn install:install-file  -Dfile=path-to-your-artifact-jar \
                          -DgroupId=your.groupId \
                          -DartifactId=your-artifactId \
                          -Dversion=version \
                          -Dpackaging=jar \
                          -DlocalRepositoryPath=path-to-specific-local-repo
```

I would not recommend this as a general solution, but it will work until you resolve your environment issues.

Comment: Thanks but the environment restricts that test artifacts cannot be present.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption is that tests must succeed for a build to succeed. You can skip the tests, but having a build automatically skip tests just because it can't run them seems dangerous - that's the theory at least, and explains why what you try to do isn't easy in maven.

I've never done that , but you might be able to solve the problem by having a conditional build and only activate the test lifecycle if the dependency is available:

```
    <profiles>
      <profile>
        <activation>
          <-- something relying on dependency presence/absence? -->
        </activation>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
      </profile>
    </profiles>
```

I couldn't find an easy way to activate on a dependency being present, so you'll probably have to use the file-based activation (ew....) - which in turn might require a 'fake' project to try and download the dep for you first (make the dep optional there).

It might even get more complex than that if skipTests in that context doesn't work, and you need a profile based build.

If it gets ugly enough, what I'd do is just split the project in two (jars/tests) - that way the twisted logic would not 'contaminate' the main project - and nasty stuff (antrun is your friend!) in the test project isn't as bad as that project ultimately doesn't produce anything that others depend on.

Answer (score 0):

Using **-Dmaven.test.skip=true** will get you MOST of what you need.  It then depends on the plugin you are to process your test resources.

I found that some other plugins allow you to skip their actions too, and you can then reuse the property value from maven.test.skip

For example:
http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html

This has a skip configuration.
Making the following change to your configuration for that execution will skips that action.

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip> 
</configuration>
```

This question may be from 2011, but I'm hoping the next person will find it useful.

This is really useful for development environments like eclipse where it is using mvn to update classes every time you compile.  If you can skip a slow action, you also get a speedup.